# Scaling the axes in `pgfplots` to plot the square root function

Tags: pgfplots

What is wrong with this code.  I use `unit vector ratio={2 1}` to get a better visualization of the square root function and cube root function.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5in,width=4.5in, clip=false,
    unit vector ratio={2 1},
    xmin=-100,xmax=100,
    ymin=-5,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-5:10,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:100, blue] {x^(1/2)} node[anchor=north west, pos=0.75, font=\footnotesize]{$y = \sqrt{x}$};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-100:0, green] {-(-x)^(1/3)}
node[anchor=south east, pos=0.25, font=\footnotesize]{$y = \sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{x}$};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:100, green] {x^(1/3)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `unit vector ratio={2 1}` the unit vector for the `x`-direction is twice as long as the unit vector in `y`-direction.  But there are only 15 units in y-direction in your plot while there are 200 in `x`-direction.  So if the `y`-axis should be 1cm long the `x`-axis must be 1cm*(200/15)*2=26.7cm long!

I would suggest to use something like `unit vector ratio={1 4}`
resulting in

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5in,width=4.5in, clip=false,
    unit vector ratio={1 4},
    xmin=-100,xmax=100,
    ymin=-5,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-5:10,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:100, blue] {x^(1/2)} node[anchor=north west, pos=0.75, font=\footnotesize]{$y = \sqrt{x}$};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-100:0, green] {-(-x)^(1/3)}
node[anchor=south east, pos=0.25, font=\footnotesize]{$y = \sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{x}$};
\addplot[samples=501, domain=0:100, green] {x^(1/3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Because of the question in a comment:

You set `width=4.5in` and `height=4.5in`.  If you do not set `unit vector ratio`, `ymin` and `ymax` you get a square

[image]

```
\begin{axis}[height=4.5in,width=4.5in, clip=false,
    %unit vector ratio={1 4},
    xmin=-100,xmax=100,
    %ymin=-5,ymax=10,
    %restrict y to domain=-5:10,
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    ...
    ]
```

With `unit vector ratio={1 4}` the scaling of the `y`-axis changes but you have still a square

[image]

```
\begin{axis}[height=4.5in,width=4.5in, clip=false,
    unit vector ratio={1 4},
    xmin=-100,xmax=100,
    %ymin=-5,ymax=10,
    %restrict y to domain=-5:10,
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    ...
    ]
```

But then you restrict the displayed `y`-range using `ymin` and `ymax` and so the height of the `y`-axis is decreased.

[image]

```
\begin{axis}[height=4.5in,width=4.5in, clip=false,
    %unit vector ratio={1 4},
    xmin=-100,xmax=100,
    ymin=-5,ymax=10,
    %restrict y to domain=-5:10,
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    ...
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, this is about the display that I want.  I think that I will extend the `y`-axis upwards a bit more, but the graphs of the functions themselves are exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Comment: What do the values of `4.5in` in the `axis` environment do for the display?  I have `height=4.5in` and `width=4.5in`, but the display is not a square.  (I do not want it to be a square.)

Comment: @Adelyn See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the graph illustrating it.  So, `restrict y to domain=-5:10` restricts the `y`-axis to the interval `[-5, 10]`.  What would `ymin=-5` and `ymax=10` do for the graph?  Would that plot only those points on the graph for which the `y`-value is between `-5` and `10`?  Without  `restrict y to domain=-5:10`, would the `y`-axis go between `-25` and `25` if `xmin=-100` and `xmax=100`?

Comment: `ymin` and `ymax` restricts the shown range of the `y`-axis. If you remove `ymin=-5` and `ymax=10` from your code the `y` axis would go from `-25` to `25` with your settings of `width`, `height`, `xmin`, `xmax` and `unit vector ratio={1 4}`.  Note that  `restrict y to domain=-5:10` restricts only the shown plot but not the `y`-axis. And it has no effect in your example becaus all `y` values of both plots are largen than `-5` and lower or equal than `10` if `xmin=-100` and `xmax=100`.

Comment: OK.  `ymin=a` and `ymax=b` determines that the `y`-axis spans the interval `[a, b]`, and `restrict y to domain=-m:M` allows only those points on the graph of the function for which the `y` value is between `m` and `M` to be plotted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The given code gives the expected result. The main problem is that you scaled the wrong parameter, so you squeezed the wrong axis.

Also you provide `width`, `height` and all axis limits (i.e. `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`), so the question is, what has the higher priority to execute or it depends on the given order of the keys.

Here is a reduced code showing that everything works as expected. Hopefully this helps to modify your code to your needs, but I cannot help any more here, because your question is quite "vague".

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % define a scaling factor for `unit vector ratio'
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{10}
        % define a lenght to draw in y direction for testing, 
        % if `unit vector ratio' is working as expected
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ydirection}{5}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        unit vector ratio={1 \factor},
        restrict y to domain=-5:10,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ]
        \addplot[samples=51, domain=0:100, blue] {x^(1/2)}
            node[anchor=north west, pos=0.75, font=\footnotesize]
                {$y = \sqrt{x}$};
        \addplot[samples=51, domain=0:100, green] {x^(1/3)};

        % draw some lines for testing, if the `unit vector ratio' is
        % working as expected and save the beginning and ending coordinates
        \draw [red] (0,0) -- +(axis direction cs: \factor*\Ydirection,0)
            coordinate [pos=0] (origin)
            coordinate [pos=1] (x)
        ;
        \draw [red] (0,0) -- +(axis direction cs: 0,\Ydirection)
            coordinate [pos=1] (y)
        ;
    \end{axis}
    \path   let
                % calculate "dummy" coordinates giving the coordinates
                % of the difference between the points
                % (because the one is at the origin it should give
                %  the same values as the first coordinate)
                \p1 = ($ (x) - (origin) $),
                \p2 = ($ (y) - (origin) $),
                % calculate the vector lengths of the "dummy points"
                \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
                \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
            in
                % plot the calculated length of the vectors, which should
                % be identical (if there are no rounding errors)
                node [anchor=west]  at (x) {\n1}
                node [anchor=south] at (y) {\n2}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]